# n = pq where p and q are odd prime numbers, gcd(c,n) = 1, c < n, show at most $\frac{φ(n)}{4}$ of c satisfy $ord_n(c)$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

Suppose n = pq where p and q are distinct odd prime numbers. Show that, out of the φ(n) different integers c satisfying 1 < c < n and gcd(c,n) = 1, at most $\frac{φ(n)}{4}$ of them have
the property that the multiplicative order of c mod n is odd.

### Attempt

Let the multiplicative order of c be x:
$$ord_n(c) = x$$
It means
$$c^x \equiv 1 \mod n$$
Since gcd(c,n)=1, then $x|φ(n)$
$$
φ(n)\\
=φ(pq)\\
=φ(p)φ(q)\\
=(p-1)(q-1)
$$
So $x|(p-1)$ or $x|(q-1)$, but not both, since we are looking for odd x, but p-1 and q-1 are even.

There are at least $\phi(p-1)$ numbers can be a divisor of p-1.

Out of these numbers, some $\frac{p-1}{2}$ will be prime. So:
$$\phi(p-1)>1+\phi(\frac{p-1}{2})=1+(\frac{p-1}{2}-1)=\frac{p-1}{2}$$
$$\phi(q-1)>\frac{q-1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline . . .

Let $G=\bigl\{c\in\{1,...,n-1\}\mid\gcd(c,n)=1\bigr\}$ represent the group of units, mod $n$.

Let $H=\{c\in G\mid\text{ord}(c)\;\text{is odd}\}$.

Show that $H$ is closed under multiplication, hence $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

The set $\bigl\{\{c,c^{-1}\}\mid c\in H\bigr\}$ is a partition of $H$ (why?), and for all $c\in H$ with $c\ne 1$, the set $\{c,c^{-1}\}$ has cardinality $2$ (why?).

It follows that $H$ has odd order.

But the order of $G$ is $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ which is a multiple of $4$.

Then $|G/H|=|G|/|H|\ge 4$, hence $|H|\le\phi(n)/4$.

Comment: I did not get how you showed $H$ has an odd cardinality and the part ||/||≥4, how can we rule out the case ||=8, ||=3 and 8/3<4?

Comment: @Mzq: The set $H{\setminus}\{1\}$ can be partitioned into sets of the form $\{c,c^{-1}\}$, all of which have cardinality $2$. It follows that the cardinality of $H{\setminus}\{1\}$ is even, hence the cardinality of $H$ is odd.

Comment: @Mzq: Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the order of $H$ must divide the order of $G$, so you can't have $|G|=8,|H|=3$. The fraction $|G|/|H|$ must reduce to a positive integer, and moreover, it must be a multiple of $4$ (since $|G|$ is a multiple of $4$ and $|H|$ is odd).

Comment: The question given 1 < c < n, so shouldn't H dose not contain 1?

Comment: @Mzq: I defined $H$ to include $1$, and my argument shows that $|H|\le\phi(n)/4$. If we then remove $1$, the inequality becomes strict (i.e., $|H{\setminus}\{1\}| < \phi(n)/4$).

Comment: why $c^{-1}$ is in H? where $cc^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$

Comment: @Mzq: The order of $c^{-1}$ is the same as the order of $c$.  The proof is easy. Try it.

Comment: is it because the definition of Group: The inverse for an element in the group must exist in the group? the inverse of the identity element is itself? dose that mean all group has odd number of elements?

Comment: @Mzq: $H$ is a subset of the finite group $G$, so once you've shown that $H$ is closed under multiplication, it follows (fairly easily) that $H$ is closed under inversion, and from those facts, we get that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: To confirm: for $a,b \in H$, ord(ab) is odd $\to$ H is closed under multiplication, $k=ord(c) \to c^k\equiv 1 \mod n \to (c^k)^{-1}\equiv 1 \to (c^{-1})^{k}\equiv 1 \to c^{-1} \in H$?

Comment: @Mzq: It's true that $H$ is closed under multiplication, but that claim requires justification (just a few steps).